Should I keep rusted Shree Yantra in pooja mandir
I have energized Shree Yantra in my Pooja mandir at home for more than 7 years.  Over the time, it has rusted at tiny  spots because of water seeping through while cleaning.  Should I continue keeping it in my mandir.  Since I had it for long time, I don’t feel comfortable removing it.  Please advise.****

Is it made of copper?

When we bought it, they said it’s gold plated

As long as the Yantra does not get deformed (out of shape) you can keep it. You can wash the Yantra with soap water to remove rust or dirt .. unless it is made from iron it won't get rust.
